# Executing Immediate Function

Tags: javascript, function, coffeescript

CoffeeScript compiled this code:

`mod = (num) -> num % 2`

into:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.7.1
(function() {
  var mod;

  mod = function(num) {
    return num % 2;
  };

}).call(this);
```

How can I call this JavaScript immediate function?

For example, I'd like to call `mod.apply(5)`.

Comment: Compile with `--bare` or export to `window`

Comment: thanks, elclanrs. Care to answer for credit? So, with the `coffee -c file.js`, it wouldn't be possible to pass in an argument to the immediate function?

Comment: As the code stands there, you can't call it from outside the block because it's only scoped to inside the block.  You will have to change your CoffeeScript or your compile options.  Also, what you want is `mod(5)`, not `mod.apply(5)`.

Comment: `mod.apply(5)` doesn't make sense. Read the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to get a better idea of how `.apply()` works.

Comment: Your intentions aren't really clear from the wording of the question. What would you like the value of "mod" to be?

Comment: @Pointy, I'm thinking of `mod` as a curried function (in a Haskell sense), I'd like to be able to pass in an argument to `mod`. I'm not sure how (if possible) to do that in the compiled `mod` JavaScript code.

Comment: Do you mean you want to pass the argument in *later*, or as part of the statement that assigns the function to "mod"?  That's the part that's not clear.

Comment: Ah. I want to define `mod` and then, **later**, pass in an argument. I want `mod` to be a function, and then pass in values to calculate, for example, `mod(5)`.

Comment: Once you've got a reference to a function (which is what the value of "mod" will be, then you can just use it like a function any time you want. See my answer update.

Comment: You might want to read [MDN - Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions), which explains how functions work in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, Felix. Good link above and the new one you added. I'll do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
mod = ((num) -> num % 2) 5
```

That's *not* the same as `mod.apply(5)`, which would not call the "mod" function such that "num" is `5`. Instead it'd call the function such that `this` was `5`, which I doubt is what you really wanted to do.

The result of my code above would be to set "mod" to `1`, which is `5 % 2`.

Now, if you just want to call "mod" *later*, you would use your original code and then just do it:

```
mod5 = mod 5
```

Comment: Ah, I understand your answer now, thanks. However, how can I correct this [javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/Ca5u7/) to pass 5 as an argument to the immediate function?

Comment: @KevinMeredith Well the code in that fiddle makes no sense; you don't have a variable called "mod" outside that immediately executed function. You'd have to **assign** the result of that function call to some variable, and then call *that*. *edit* and even if you did, it wouldn't work because it's missing a `return` statement.

Comment: @KevinMeredith I think part of the problem may be the way you're interpreting the semantics of the translated Coffeescript. I'm not a Coffeescript user (or fan, to be honest), so I can't really go too deep on that subject.

Comment: I think I may have not understood the question just right, I thought OP was having trouble executing the function globally...

Comment: Thanks, @Pointy. Your question about my misinterpretation made me re-think. By defining simply an immediate function in CoffeeScript, the output JavaScript is simply an immediate function without any arguments passed to it. I was incorrectly expecting a way to call `mod`'s immediate function with an argument.

Answer (score 1):

You can compile with `--bare` or `-b`, which doesn't generate the wrapping function:

```
coffee -c -b file.js
```

Or you can export your variables to `window`:

```
window.mod = (x) -> x % 2
```

Or in NodeJS:

```
mod = (x) -> x % 2

module.exports = {mod}
```

`apply` calls a function with a context, what we call `this`, and an array of arguments. `apply` differs from `call` in that you can execute variadic functions (functions with any number of arguments) dynamically. You'd use it like so:

```
mod.apply null, [2]
```

Where `null` is the context, which doesn't matter in this case because your `mod` function doesn't use `this`.

If you were to write it like this:

```
mod = -> @ % 2
```

Then you can call it with a context:

```
mod.call 2
mod.apply 2
```